# Retorno do Qt durante o release

Tags: c++, qt

Quando compilo meu projeto como *debug*, ele funciona normalmente, porém quando tento compilar em *release* aparece a seguinte mensagem no compile Output:

> cc1plus: error: argument to '-O' should be a non-negative integer, 'g', 's' or 'fast'
>   make: *** [main.o] Error 1
>   ... : The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>
> Error while building/deploying project 'nome_projeto' (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.0 GCC 64bit) When executing step "Make"

Alguém saberia o motivo?

Comment: O problema provavelmente esta no seu `.pro`. Adicione ele na sua pergunta. Adicione também a linha de comando sendo executada no momento do erro.

Comment: Tive esse problema a um tempo atrás, mas realmente não lembro como resolvi.

Comment: Obrigado @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira pela dica, realmente ajudou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema pelo seguinte motivo, por meu aplicativo ser multiplataforma (windows/linux), adicionei:

```
-QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2

-QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Od
```

Para retirar umas mensagens do meu compilador de `C` do windows, porém não coloquei a tag `win32:` nestas linhas e o compilador c do linux não entendia, após adiciona-lá, funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Como disse que esta solução resolveu seu problema tem a opção de marcar esta resposta como aceita.

Comment: @GiovaniRaciPaganini sim, porém somente após dois dias após a postagem da resposta.

Comment: Ah sim, havia esquecido hehe.

Comment: A boa resposta, infelizmente ninguém iria conseguir (eu acho) responder por que não havia o código do `.pro` como o Vinícius solicitou. Mas mesmo assim boa dica :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo com sua afirmação, mas assim que o amigo Vinícius comentou fui olhar meu .pro e então notei o erro, então não vi necessidade de postar o trecho errado na pergunta e sim uma resposta já com a solução.

Comment: A sim, não é bem isso que eu quero dizer, o que eu quero dizer é que sempre poste códigos relevantes seguindo estas dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :) No caso nas próximas questões que você vier a fazer

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, muito obrigado por sua sugestão.